# How can i create some ListViews during runtime and place them in different order

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I want to create some ListViews during runtime and place them in different order, depends on how many will created (2 ListViews will placed in the middle, 4 will placed more close to the edges, etc).

I want not more than 8 ListViews.

Can I have a suggestion how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it programmatically:

```
ListView lv = new ListView(MainActivity.this);
lv.setLayoutParams(); //customize your layoutparams
addView(lv);
```

Or you can have everything in your layout and show and hide them using `view.setVisibility()`.

Or you can have different layout files and according to a condition call your 'setContentView()' method with a certain layout.